# tkinter insert text with a given margin

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the text lines I insert in my Text widget have a different left margin each time (depending on their level in a hierarchy of headers, word-processor style):

```
# The Solar system
The Solar System[a] consists of the Sun and its planetary system of ...
  ## Inner Planets
  The four inner or terrestrial planets...
    ### Mercury
    Mercury (0.4 AU from the Sun) is the closest planet to the Sun and...
```

I know that I can set lmargin1/lmargin2 in a tag definition http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/text.html, but I dont want to create a new tag each time I have to increment/decrement the left margin.

There is no way to do it as an option to text.insert() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice is to use tags. Tags are cheap and easy, and specifically for solving this sort of problem. You can store the tags in a dict and reference them via the indentation level, then you only have to create and configure the tag the first time you add something at a specific indentation level.

You can, of course, also use tabs to indent a line of text. The difference between tabs and using tags is that using tags gets you proper behavior when a line of text wraps, whereas a tab is literally just a tab at the start of the line. If the linen wraps it will wrap to the left margin rather than to where the start of the line is.

Comment: oh well, I feared that - but I'm sure, now that you confirm it. Thx as always Bryan

Comment: @alessandro: don't be afraid. Tags are the right tool for the job. They are remarkably powerful and flexible, and quite easy to use. Just create a `insert_at_level` method, and hide the details in there. It's literally just half a dozen lines of code.